# What would be the voltage across a load at a junction point where two current sources are connected in series?

Tags: current, current-source

If two current sources are connected in series,then what would be the voltage at their junction point across a load?

Comment: If an immovable object encounters an irresistible force, what happens? No such physical reality exists.

Comment: Current by itself does not produce voltage. Though, realistically, current can't exists without some sort of differential driving force. This driving force is thus your voltage, or the resistances the currents encounter would determine the voltage. From a pure current perspective... I'd assume it can't be determined.

Answer (score 1):

If the two current sources have exactly the same value, the voltage would be indeterminate. If they have different values, the voltage will be either positive or negative infinity, depending on which source has the greater current.

Answer (score 1):

If the current sources are connected like this (arguably in series):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQS56o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then the voltage at the upper junction point is simply RL(I2 - I1)